# convert python list to numpy array boolean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big list in python like small example and want to make a numpy array which is boolean.

small example:

```
li = ['FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE']

I tried to change it using the following line:

out = array(li, dtype = bool)
```

and then I got this output:

```
out = array([ True, True, True, True, True, True], dtype=bool)
```

but the problem is that they are all True. how can I make the same array but elements should remain the same meaning False should be False and True should be True in the new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the strings to boolean literals using `str.title` and [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
import ast
import numpy as np

li = ['FALSE', 'FALSE', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE', 'FALSE']
arr = np.array([ast.literal_eval(x.title()) for x in li])
# array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

You could otherwise use a simple *list comprehension* if you have only those two in your list:

```
arr = np.array([x=='TRUE' for x in li])
# array([False, False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Keep in mind that non-empty strings are *truthy*, so coercing them to bool like you did will produce an array with all elements as `True`.

Answer (score 4):

`bool('True')` and `bool('False')` always return True because strings `'True'`and `'False'` are not empty

You can create afunction to convert `string` to `bool`

```
def string_to_bool(string):
    if string == 'True':
        return True
    elif string == 'False':
        return False
>>> string_to_bool('True')
True
```

Comment: then what is the solution to get the output i WANT

Comment: `elif s` should be `elif string` Also to be compatible with OPs data, the comparison should be to `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`.